# Can we use the Entry class directly to create a single key:value object instead of a set of key:value pairs as done in HashMaps in Java?

Tags: java, hashmap

I read in Oracle documentation that HashMap has static inner class Entry which implements Map.Entry.

```
HashMap<Integer,String> hm = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
```

I also read this from documentation that
Static nested classes are accessed using the enclosing class name: `OuterClass.StaticNestedClass`

For example, to create an object for the static nested class, use this syntax:

```
OuterClass.StaticNestedClass nestedObject = new OuterClass.StaticNestedClass();
```

However, when I modify the above piece of code to this:

```
HashMap.Entry<Integer,String> hm = new HashMap.Entry<Integer,String>();
```

It gives the error: cannot instantiate Map.Entry

Do you know what can be done here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleEntry.html) to create a standalone `Entry`:

```
Map.Entry<K, V> entry = new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(key, value);
```

Comment: @ishaagarwal You can thank me by accepting the answer.

Comment: @ishaagarwal Or `AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry`. Also, Java 9 has a static factory method `Map.entry(k, v)` that returns a `Map.Entry` instance, though not necessarily one of the `AbstractMap.*Entry` instances.